# Overlay div with Multi-Column layout breaks in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a **horizontal multi-column layout** using **html and css only** and i was trying to add an overlay gradient div to the boxes but i'm facing a strange problem:
Overlay div looks fine over all blocks in FF/IE11/Edge/Safari but **disappears from the upper right blocks chrome only**.

[Chrome Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr5Kd.jpg)

HTML/CSS Code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper { width:90%; max-width:1130px;  margin:auto; padding:3em 0; }

.masonry, .inner {
 -moz-column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
 -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
 column-gap: 30px;
}

.masonry article.brick { width:100%;  height:300px; }
.inner article { width:100%; height:150px; }

.masonry article { margin-bottom: 30px; border:1px solid red; }

.masonry article { position:relative;  } .masonry article a { color:red; }
.masonry article h3 { position:absolute;  bottom:30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0;right: 0; width:90%;  z-index:5; }
.masonry .inner article h3 { bottom:0px;}

.overlay{ width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)); opacity:0.9; z-index:3; transition: all .3s; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="masonry">
  
  <article class="brick"><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Big</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
    
  <div class="inner">
   <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
  </div>
   
  <article class="brick"><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Big</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   
 </div>
</div>
```

codePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgegxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange, I'm leaning towards this being a bug. However, as a fix, just don't use `opacity`. Set the opacity in gradient itself to fade it down.

Seems to be related to the way you formatted `.inner` and your use of columns.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper { width:90%; max-width:1130px;  margin:auto; padding:3em 0; }

.masonry, .inner {
 -moz-column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
 -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
 column-gap: 30px;
}

.masonry article.brick { width:100%;  height:300px; }
.inner article { width:100%; height:150px; }

.masonry article { margin-bottom: 30px; border:1px solid red; }

.masonry article { position:relative;  } .masonry article a { color:red; }
.masonry article h3 { position:absolute;  bottom:30px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0;right: 0; width:90%;  z-index:5; }
.masonry .inner article h3 { bottom:0px;}

.overlay{ width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.9)); z-index:3; transition: all .3s; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="masonry">
  
   <article class="brick"><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Big</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
    
   <div class="inner">
    <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
    <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
    <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
    <article><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Sub</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   </div>
   
   <article class="brick"><a href="#"><h3>Post Title - Big</h3><div class="overlay"></div></a></article>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It works! 
Me too, i think it's more of a bug than a misuse of css columns,I hope it gets fixed asap.

thanks alot Serg.